# Modifying responses in service worker requests to be an image

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

Hello and thank you in advance.

My question is about responding to a network request using ***ServiceWorker***. I am able to handle it in case of a text or html, but when I am trying to deal with an ***image*** I am failing, here is the code I have:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response){
        if(response.status === 404){
            return new Response('The page wasn\'t found');
        }
        return response;  
     }).catch(function(){
            return new Response('The network is totally failed');
     })
    );
 });
```

The snippet above is working when dealing with text and html but when I am trying with an ***image*** it brings a totally black screen. Here what I used but it didn't work.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response){
        if(response.status === 404){
            return new Response('/imgs/sunset.gif', {headers:{'Content-Type':'image/gif'}});
        }
        return response;  
     }).catch(function(){
            return new Response('The network is totally failed');
     })
    );
 });
```

Hopefully you can help me in knowing what I am missing. thanks.

Comment: I think what's actually happening is that the content of the response is the text "/imgs/sunset.gif" and not the actual gif. You will need to create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) with the image data and pass that as the first argument to the `Response` constructor.

Comment: I second schroffl. The first argument should be a Blob, an ArrayBuffer, or TypedArray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace your line :

```
return new Response('/imgs/sunset.gif', {headers:{'Content-Type':'image/gif'}});
```

By :

```
return new Response("<img src='/imgs/sunset.gif'/>", {headers:{'Content-Type': 'text/html'}});
```

You want to display a gif in your page, so you have to add a html content with  and tell its source src.

Or easier solution you can only write this :

```
return fetch('/imgs/sunset.gif');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fetch to get image or gif from files like below.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {           
        return fetch("/path/to/404error.gif");
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function() {
      return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed!");
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution and the following works:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 404) {
        return fetch('/imgs/sunset.gif');
      }
      return response;
    }).catch(function() {
      return new Response("Uh oh, that totally failed!");
    })
  );
});
```