# Service worker: intercept responses

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, service-worker

I know that I can use a service worker to intercept outgoing `fetch` operations, and even generate custom responses to them, e.g.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {                   
  if (/\.jpg$/.test(event.request.url)) {                          
    event.respondWith(
      fetch('/images/anotherimage.jpg'));                               
  }
});
```

However, what if I want to intercept the response to a given `fetch` request before that response is passed back to the page? Is this doable?

To be clear, I do not in any way want to modify the request itself - I just want to access the response to it.

Comment: You can use `waitUntil`, see the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent

Comment: you surely can hijack responses using `respondWith()`, though there's no mention of intercepting responses in MDN docs.

Comment: This is also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378383/600135

Comment: @GrafiCode If "intercepting the response" means catching and possibly changing it, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: `FetchEvent:  It contains information about the fetch, including the request and how the receiver will treat the response.` Where's the response?

Comment: according to this https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/fallback-response you have to fetch event.request from within the service worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you mean you'd like to add logic to a service worker so that it requests a resource, and then modifies the response from the network, resulting in a response that's passed back to the page that is a mix of what you'd get from the network and what the service worker added.

If so, the answer is yes, you can do that for same-origin responses, and for cross-origin responses when CORS is used. (You can't modify [opaque responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109789/what-limitations-apply-to-opaque-responses), which is what you get when making a cross-origin request without using CORS.)

Here's an example of a `fetch` handler that responds to requests for an hypothetical `/api` endpoint that returns JSON my making the request to `/api`, and then adding in an additional field to the API response before returning the response to the page.

```js
async function modifyAPIResponse(request) {
  const apiResponse = await fetch(request);
  const json = await apiResponse.json();
  json.extraField = 'set by fetch handler';

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(json), {
    // Ensure that the Content-Type: and other headers are set.
    headers: apiResponse.headers,
  });
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.pathname === '/api') {
    event.respondWith(modifyAPIResponse(event.request));
  }
});
```